# Issues with os.rename() - getting [WinError 5] Access is denied:

Tags: python, windows, permissions, file-permissions

I have been doing some research around the `os.rename` and its intermittent issues while running python code in Windows environment.

Here is my code:

```
#unzip extraction and save just .csv files
with zipfile.ZipFile("EO_Data.zip", "r") as EO_Boards_Cards:
    FileNames = EO_Boards_Cards.namelist()
    for fileName in FileNames:
        if fileName.endswith(".csv"):
            EO_Boards_Cards.extract(fileName, path=desktop)

#rename and move extraction to path.cwd
for files in os.listdir(desktop):
    if files.startswith('enterprise'):
        os.rename("personal path"+ "\\" + files, "Raw_data")
```

While most of the time the code runs okay, I have been getting this annoying message from time to time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\personal path\EO_Boards_Cards_ScoreCard_v1.py", line 26, in <module>
    os.rename("personal path" + "\\" + files, "Raw_data")
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\enterpriseoperations5_20210412_153357' -> 'Raw_data'
```

Any idea of how to prevent this intermittent issue to happen?

Comment: Do you have (or recently had) a file open in that folder, either in Windows Explorer or any other program?

Comment: @MattDMo: "that folder" is the user's desktop folder, so I venture a guess and say "yes" — but suspect you're probably right about the being the cause of the problem.

Comment: Hi Matt/Martineau. Yes, I work with plenty of files in my desktop. One pattern that I have noticed is that if I restart my PC it will run with no problems at all. However when I change the project to something else and then close everything and just leave open my Visual Studio Code to run the program again it fails with the error above. Any idea of the problem? - Thank you again for looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the directory/drive of your whole program to some other directory. C: drive causes these permissionError.
I was getting same error. Just changing the position of whole folder from C: to D: drive solved the issue.